# MYSQL using temporary when Group By

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I have this query:

```
SELECT m.Number
FROM table m
WHERE m.IdA = _IdA
    AND m.IdB = _IdB
    AND m.IdC = _IdC
GROUP BY m.Number
ORDER BY m.Number;
```

Where _IdA, _IdB & _IdC are the parameters.
If I check it with EXPLAIN it says no using temporary, but if the values of those parameters doesn't return any row EXPLAIN says "using temporary"

I'd like to avoid using temporary....Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a **composite** index (`IdA, IdB, IdC, Number`).

Comment: @Mike Does the query use this index when EXPLAIN says `using temporary`?

Comment: Yes; Using where; Using index...and it appears also under key column

Comment: @MikeJohnson Is this query slower than another one?

Comment: @MikeJohnson Keep in mind that MySQL may decide to use different execution plan in different situations. Temporary tables are not always evil. MySQL thinks that temporary table works better in this particular situation. I think this happens because MySQL uses just a part of an index. Grouping and ordering an empty table is a very fast operation :)